# openCV optical flow in python

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I am writing image analysis program in python and am trying to use the `cv.CalcOpticalFlowFarneback`. I figured out most of the things and the analysis works, however, I would like to play a little with `flags` parameter. In cv documentation it says that flags is an integer and the description is the following:

```
flags –
Operation flags that can be a combination of the following:
OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW Use the input flow as an initial flow approximation.
OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN ...
```

The question is how do I set flag to use either one of the options or both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
flags = OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW | OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN
```

The `|` (pipe) character is a bitwise or. A common way of doing flags is to use different powers of 2 for each flag. For instance, if `OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW` is 2 and `OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN` is 8 then their combination is 1010 in binary.

Their actual values can be seen in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html):

```
OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW = 4
OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN = 256
```

Comment: Thanks Koobz, it does seem right, except why do you think it's 2 and 8 vs 1 and 3 (01 and 11 in binary). In other words why do you need each flag to be 2 digits instead of one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field explains it probably better than me. Each bit is essentially an exclusive way to toggle a particular flag. So if you have 8 bits, and each bit corresponds to some flag being on and off, you can compactly communicate all 256 combinations and easily answer questions such as is the flag at the 4th bit position enabled using bitwise masks. E.g. 0111 & 0100 = 0100 which != 0 and (therefore generally "true"). 0111 & 1000 = 0, false.